# how to extend image from a laptop to 2 other monitors using a usb c dock

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga, usb-c

I have a lenovo C740 laptop and im trying to connect two monitors to the laptop through a usb-c dock. Here is the [usb c dock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tiroe.jpg). One monitor is connected to the dock by vga while the other is connected by HDMI and the dock is connect to the laptop via usb C. The settings are set to extend however its only picking up one additional monitor. The third monitor is simply duplicating the 2nd monitor. I was trying various cords to make sure both monitors are extended to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the laptop display as the third display.  See this page :

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000025673/graphics.html